# I am trying to merge three pages to one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

This is my first question.
I am trying to merge three pages. A register page, a pricing page, and a plans configuration page.
The issue I am having is that I can not get all three pages code to work together.
I have one master page for all three of the pages. Unfortunately, since I signed a NDA, I can not share the propriety code. If some one has an article on how to make the three pages as one and make all of the code work, please let me know.
I did look at a codebehind option but not sure how that works with visual studio using C# and HTML. Thank you all.

Comment: just copy controls and function of each pages in one page

Comment: but it will work with only one master page since you hv three master page for three pages

Comment: you can share your code the only things is hide your database credential

Comment: You don't have to show proprietary code. Just create a simple example that illustrates the problem and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As weird as this sounds you may want to incorporate some php into the mix (I use it for simplicity and security purposes) but turn the primary (all in one) doc into a php for  example

```
Index.php 
<!Doctype html>
<style> ... </style>
<body> 
<?php include("nav.php") ?> <!-- I have the name in same section of the directory-->
<div id="section1 class="first">
<?php include("code1.html") ?>
</div>

<div id="section2 class="second">
<?php include("code2.html") ?>
</div>

<div id="section3 class="third">
<?php include("code3.html") ?>
</div>
</body>
```

This is of course assuming you know how you want this styled and the include code can render in your code from you directory.

It's a little php but all edits to the framework would be done in this index and the edits to the other codes would be on their respective files.

Again keep in mind this is if you have access to those directories.

Comment: Note: also that if you files that have the same class names but the css for those those classes is different, that may result in unexpected changes to formatting. Same thing goes for script funtions.